# Are questions about general design of a Mathematica program on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

When I write small projects in Mathematica, I run into such problem: I know ways to implement the functionality of small parts, but having problem selecting the most Mathematica-style way to group them together, to be specific, it may concern the efficiency/connivence/convention about the styles. However, these question may fall into "too broad", "too localized", "opinion based" etc, that's why I'm asking.

For example, I am developing a program that analysis a large set of data, some possible questions about design could be:

- Should I load the large data into a global variable, or make an object to access like `obj["Property"]`?
- Should some settings about analysis written and initialized first at the beginning at the notebook, or make them options for specific function?
- Should I use a traditional algorithm, or use an one-line pattern matching to do some operations?
- Should I make all the code inside `.m` file, or leave some certain code in the `.nb` file?
- To what extent should I preprocess my data (preprocess takes more time/memory in advance while process at function results in redundant calculations)?

(Of course I will describe questions more clearly in practice.)

My past attempts are "ask an approach I don't know how to write, and hopefully someone will suggest another method", and a successful example is: [How to prevent substitution in a part of an expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111768/how-to-prevent-substitution-in-a-part-of-an-expression)
,where Leonid gave me both. I imagine if I asked "what is generally a good way to write a parser for scheme in Mathematica?", and it will be closed. But I believe if I present the brief description of whole project, it's easy for others to get my intention.

Comment: I think these kind of questions would fall under the [tag:guidelines] and [tag:programming] tags. Checking the questions under these tags might give you some suggestions about how to formulate your questions in an on-topic way. Especially, not asking "Should I ..." but something more concrete (advantages, performance, readability, how to, ...) with a minimal working example should reduce the risk of being off-topic.

Comment: I am **not** asking that specific question, that is only an example, I am not needing any answers to any of the questions listed. To whoever want to close this post: I would like to know why this post itself is opinion based, since many questions about allowed questions exist on meta.

Answer (score 5):

This question is good example of one that should be closed because any answers can only be opinion-based. However, I will give my opinion.

The design issues brought up in this question are important ones, but no general answer can be given that will be the right answer for all *Mathematica* projects. *Mathematica* is simply too big a tool box, applicable to too many kinds of programming projects, that there is no single design paradigm that can apply in general.

Therefore, in my opinion, a question of the kind described above would only admissible to *Mathematica*.SE if it described the specifics of a project in considerable detail and asked a focused question on one (or maybe a very few) design issues. I would not want to see a project description followed by the question: What is the best overall design to implement this project?